# oracle join queries samples

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sample

I am new to oracle and was learning about joins. In the pdf which I am using currently there is only one example per each type of joins. I also searched in the internet for few examples but all I could find was explanation with 1-2 examples.

I was looking for a study guide or website which gives me a set of 40-50 examples with answers so that I can verify my answers.

Can someone please suggest me a good site where I can practice or download a pdf which has join queries with answers.

Thanks in advance

-Varun

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/Exampleouterjoinwith.htm

Comment: You could go to w3schools for the basics, and just select the SQL tag here and look at examples. Also, check out SQL Fiddle

Comment: Have a look at http://sqlzoo.net

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for your quick response and valuable inputs.
sqlzoo.net and w3schools does look the site i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of my favorite articles on SQL joins: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: great, nice tutorial! +1 for the link

Comment: While certainly nice, that site doesn't really satisfy the requirements set by the OP, does it.

Comment: @AndriyM I agree it doesn't meet the exact requirements of the OP, but requirements are always fuzzy, sometimes the customer doesn't know exactly what they need.  The site doesn't have 50+ examples, but I would argue these examples provide a solid foundation.

Comment: I agree that this link is not exactly what I am looking for, but since I am still in the learning phase, so any links/articles considered as best will always be helpful in better understanding the topic.
Thanks a lot for valuable inputs